# Python import from relative path

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

On Python 2.7 I have the following:

```
dir1/dir2/File1.py
dir1/dir3/File2.py
```

`File2.py` wants to import `File1.py`

What are the non-hacky, pythonic, standard ways of doing this?

dir1, dir2 and dir3 contain `__init__.py`

Comment: Are `dir1`, `dir2`, or `dir3` modules?

Comment: non-hacky is to make `dir1` and `dir1.dir2` into packages.

Comment: Alternatively, add `dir1/dir2` to your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: `sys.path.insert(0, 'dir1/dir2')`

Comment: Still looking for an answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
touch dir1{,/dir2}/__init__.py
```

and probably

```
touch dir1{,/dir3}/__init__.py
```

then, in `File2.py`:

```
from dir1.dir2 import File2

fram = File2.Framistan(12)
```

bonus points for `setup.py` with:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup( 
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    ...
 )
```

to tie 'em all together.

For any arbitrary `FileX.py` to see some other package, you will need to set `PYTHONPATH` in your environment.  But for an idiomatic way to do it, just use `setup()` as above.  That will put the packages you create into the search path on your behalf.

Comment: Brian, I don't understand what `setup.py` has to do with a question about relative imports.

Comment: dir3$ python File2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "File2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dir1.dir2 import File1
ImportError: No module named dir1.dir2

Answer (score 0):

With relative imports:

```
from ..dir2 import File1

File1.hello()
```

For more information, just read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

There does appear to be a preference for absolute imports among Python programmers; that example is given by [Brian Cain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31016639/707650).